# Names of bindingsources from string

Tags: vb.net

How can I do this? Is it possible?

```
Dim i As String

Dim ps() As String = {"p3", "p4", "p5", "p6", "p7", "p8", "p9", "p10", "p11"}
For Each p In ps
    i = "BS_" & p
    Dim i As New BindingSource
Next
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? You haven't stated what behaviour you want. What do you want to Bind, and what are you trying to bind it to?

Comment: What you're suggesting doesn't really make sense.  Why not just create an array of `BindingSources` instead?  If you really want to use a `String` to identify each one then use a `Dictionary` instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

I have 9 comboboxs p3,p4,p5 .....
and for each I have this code:

```
 bs_p3.DataSource = ds_pom
            bs_p3.DataMember = "P3"
            RemoveHandler p3_f.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf roletka_EditValueChanged
            p3_f.DataSource = bs_p3
            p3_f.ValueMember = "volba"
            p3_f.DisplayMember = "volba"
            p3_f.GroupMember = "skup"
            p3_f.SelectedValue = p3
            AddHandler p3_f.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf roletka_EditValueChanged
```

I want to create function where I put identification of combobox and function 
create bindingsouce for this combobox and connect it to combobox.

Like this:

```
function pripoj_combo(p as string) as integer
dim "bs_" & p as new bindingsource
"bs_" & p.DataSource = ds_pom
"bs_" & p.DataMember = p
....
end function
```